# EF Fluent API - retrieving related entities

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have project class where each Project has its WorkOrders.
Those are tables created in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
    `idProject` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idCompany` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Title` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idProject`, `idCompany`),
    INDEX `FK_project_company` (`idCompany`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_project_company` FOREIGN KEY (`idCompany`) REFERENCES `company` (`idCompany`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
;

CREATE TABLE `project_workorders` (
    `idProjectWO` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idProject` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `idWorkOrder` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`idProjectWO`, `idProject`, `idWorkOrder`),
    INDEX `FK_project_workorders_project` (`idProject`),
    INDEX `FK_project_workorders_workorder` (`idWorkOrder`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_project_workorders_project` FOREIGN KEY (`idProject`) REFERENCES `project` (`idProject`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_project_workorders_workorder` FOREIGN KEY (`idWorkOrder`) REFERENCES `workorder` (`idWorkOrder`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
```

And then there are FluentAPI configuration files

```
class ProjectConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
    {
        internal ProjectConfiguration()
        {
            this.HasKey(p => new { p.idProject , p.idCompany});
            this.Property(p => p.idProject)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.HasRequired<MaxUser>(p => p.CreatedByUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatedByID);
            this.HasMany(s => s.ProjectWO)
                .WithRequired(w=>w.Project)
                .HasForeignKey(k=>new { k.idProject,k.idProjectWO});
            this.Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
        }
    }

    class ProjectWOConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectWO>
    {
        internal ProjectWOConfiguration()
        {
            this.HasKey(p=> new { p.idProjectWO , p.idProject, p.idWorkOrder });
            this.Property(p => p.idProjectWO)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            this.HasRequired<MaxUser>(p => p.CreatedByUser)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatedByID);
            this.Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is I can not get related entities to appear in Project object.
No matter what I try , the ProjectWO sub-object is always empty.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: My first guess would be around the composite keys. if you're dealing with something like a multi-tenant scenario then use these at top-level entities, but wherever possible, avoid them in lower entities. For example for the ProjectWO, this looks like a linking table between Projects and WOs? the PK can be the idProjectWO. It can contain 2x FKs, one to Project, one to WorkOrder. There's no need to create a composite key. In most cases I leave out the FK fields in the child entity and use .Map(x=> x.MapKey("idProject"); especially if the child will have a reference entity to the parent.

Comment: Thanks, @StevePy! You re right 'ProjectWO' represents a  linking table . Now I have removed the composite keys and left only FKs. And where do I put this.Map(x=> x.MapKey("idProject"));? when i tried It says "no definition for MapKey..."

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the MapKey...  This relates to EF 6, It seems EF Core doesn't have this feature, so I'm not too sure how to define relationships without FK properties. (Hence why I tend to avoid bleeding edge tech until everyone else has gotten bloody, and screamed at the authors to make it usable. :)

Given the following entities:

```
public class Project
{
   public int IdProject { get; set; }
   public virtual List<ProjectWorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class ProjectWorkOrder
{
   public int IdProjectWO { get; set; }
   public virtual Project { get; set; }
   public virtual WorkOrder {get; set; }
   ...
}

public class WorkOrder
{ 
   public int IdWorkOrder { get; set; }
   public virtual List<ProjectWorkOrder> Projects { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

The MapKey would go in the Project entity configuration:

```
public class ProjectConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Project>
{
   public ProjectConfiguration()
   {
      ToTable("projects");
      HasKey(x => x.IdProject)
         .Property( x => x.IdProject)
         .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

      .HasMany(x => x.WorkOrders)
         .WithRequired(x => x.Project)
         .Map(x => x.MapKey("idProject")
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);


public class ProjectWorkOrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProjectWorkOrder>
{
   public ProjectWorkOrderConfiguration()
   {
      ToTable("project_workorders");
      HasKey(x=> x.IdProjectWO)
      Property(x => x.idProjectWO)
         .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

      HasRequired(x => x.Project)
         .WithMany(x => x.WorkOrders)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
      HasRequired(x => x.WorkOrder)
         .WithMany(x => x.Projects)
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
   }
}
```

By telling EF about the FK column you remove the need to declare FK values in your entity. With entities I would recommend using either reference members (i.e. The Project reference in the ProjectWorkOrder) or the FK field, or neither; but not both reference and FK. The reason for that is that when you have both the reference and a FK this can lead to confusion in the code and within EF when it comes time to save changes to an entity.  If I set a reference to an instance of an entity with an ID of 1, but then can set the FK field to "2", what do I trust EF to do? Typically to avoid this weirdness you need to add code to the setters to ensure that the reference and FK can never be set to different values. So if you're using EF Core, then that's probably the route you'd need to consider unless someone knows of a way to get .HasForeignKey or the like to deal with the schema rather than the entity.

Whether I add references back to parents would depend on what entities serve as top-level within my system. For instance if I always deal with Projects and want to get the relevant work orders and don't need to go from work orders back up to projects then my ProjectWorkOrder entity wouldn't bother having a Project or ProjectId, Project would just register a .HasMany(x=> x.WorkOrders).Map(x=>x.MapKey("idProject").WithRequired(); If I do go from WorkOrder to project then I'd have the navigation property. In some cases where I don't care about the entity details, just the association (I.e. a lookup) then in those cases I'd just map the FK. Generally these would be linked to an enumeration or name-value pair. This example assumed 2-way navigation.